# Set mail recipient name and email in .env in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to set a mail recipient email address and name in my `.env` file but this doesn't appear to be available in the code that sends a mail.

In my `.env` file I have:

```
CONTACT_US_RECIPIENT_NAME="Joe Somebody"
CONTACT_US_RECIPIENT_EMAIL=joe@example.com
CONTACT_US_SUBJECT="Enquiry from website"
```

In my controller I'm sending the mail with:

```
Mail::send('emails.contactus', $data, function($message) use($data) {
             $message->from($data['email'], $data['name']);
             $message->to(env('CONTACT_US_RECIPIENT_EMAIL'), env('CONTACT_US_RECIPIENT_NAME'))->subject(env('CONTACT_US_SUBJECT'));
        }
     );
```

However, `env('CONTACT_US_RECIPIENT_EMAIL)` is returning `null`.  I'm new to Laravel.

Am I using the  `.env` correctly?

Comment: Yes, you are using it correctly. Try to set double quotes around the e-mailaddresss, it should work then (just tested on Laravel 5.3).

Comment: Turned out that a small typo further up my stack caused the module config to be loaded incorrectly.  Thanks for confirming that I used it correctly though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
getenv('CONTACT_US_RECIPIENT_EMAIL')
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have commented, the problem was further up the stack. A typo in my module's config file caused the env variables to be set to null.